# What is the best way to detect if a User has watched a video?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code that selects all of my modules for a selected course. Each module contains a video, teaching the user about a specific course.

```
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM Modules WHERE CourseID = ". $CourseID ."";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql_query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<div class="col-md-12">';
            echo '<table class="table">';
            if($count > 1) {
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<th>Module Title</th> ';
                    echo '<th></th>';
                echo '</tr>';
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['Title'] .'</td> ';
                        echo '<td><a href="user-view-module-revised.php?ID='. $row['ID'] .'&Exam='. $row['Title'] .'&Title='. $_GET['title'] .'&CourseID='. $CourseID .'" title="Take Module" class="btn btn-success">Take Module</a></td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            }
            echo '</table>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

When they click 'Take Module' they are directed to a page with a video on. I want to somehow make the 'Take Module' buttons only work if you have completed the module before hand... For example, you can only click 'Take Module' on the 2nd Module if you have finished watching the video on the 1st.

How would you do this in PHP?

Comment: Not possible in PHP, but it might be possible in javascript

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with help of javascript ,
set an event listener to check the playback of video if playback completes push notification to server  and enable the button on success response